# Interpreting a 2d vector diagram

Tags: vectors

[image]

I found this question in the 3rd edition Strang Linear Algebra book.  I don't understand what I'm looking at in the diagram.

I think:

1) The yellow piece is the vector **W**.

2) The green piece is the vector "vector **V** minus vector **U**"

3) Vector V is not shown, however I know   **U** = 1/2**V** + 1/2**W** so   **V** = 2**U**-**W**

4) The blue piece, a dashed line.  Is it supposed to represent where the  vector **U** could terminate on any piece of that dashed line depending on the value of **V** is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's surely a bug in the picture. The label $v - u$ should be just $v$. (Or else it's a VERY bad illustration, because $v-u$ and $v$ appear to almost coincide (assuming that the label for $u$ is correct), in which case $u$ must be almost zero, which it isn't in this picture.)

Comment: One way to see that the drawing is definitely wrong is to observe that $(1)(v-u)+(1)w=u$. So $u$ isn't on the line $t (v-u)+(1-t)w$ which passes through $v-u$ and $w$.

Comment: Good observation!

Answer (score 0):

I support John's answer:

Assuming the green vector is $v - u$,  a parameterization of the dotted line is 
$$
(1-\lambda) w + \lambda (v-u)
$$ 
with $\lambda \in [0, 1]$.

For $\lambda = 1/2$ we would get 
$$
w/2 + v/2 - u/2 = u - u/2 = u/2
$$ 
instead of $u$.

Assuming the green vector is plain $v$, the parametrization of the dotted line would be
$$
(1 - \lambda) w + \lambda v
$$
and $\lambda = 1/2$ would give $w/2 + v/2 = u$, as it should.

Comment: thanks for that confirmation.  Also when I do the problems assuming the chart is just showing V and W, then everything makes sense, too.  (I'd give you an 'upvote' but I don't have enough reputation yet. sorry)

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day.